# Finding the surrounding sentence of a char/word in a string

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am trying to get sentences from a string that contain a given substring using python.

I have access to the string (an academic abstract) and a list of highlights with start and end indexes. For example:

```
{
  abstract: "...long abstract here..."
  highlights: [
    {
      concept: 'a word',
      start: 1,
      end: 10
    }
    {
      concept: 'cancer',
      start: 123,
      end: 135
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looping over each highlight, locating it's start index in the abstract (the end doesn't really matter as I just need to get a location within a sentence), and then somehow need to identify the sentence that index occurs in.

I am able to tokenize the abstract into sentences using `nltk.tonenize.sent_tokenize`, but by doing that I render the index location useless.

How should I go about solving this problem? I suppose regexes are an option but the nltk tokenizer seems such a nice way of doing it that it would be a shame not to make use of it.. Or somehow reset the start index by finding the number of chars since the previous full stop/exclamation mark/question mark?

Comment: This looks like JSON.

Comment: Yes, I am manipulating data from an API endpoint.

Comment: It might be expensive but you could go through the sentences and recompute the indexes of the sentences from the length then search for that index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, the NLTK tokenizer is really what you should be using in this situation since it is robust enough to handle delimiting mostly all sentences including ending a sentence with a "quotation." You can do something like this (`paragraph` from a random generator):

**Start with,**

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

paragraph = "How does chickens harden over the acceptance? Chickens comprises coffee. Chickens crushes a popular vet next to the eater. Will chickens sweep beneath a project? Coffee funds chickens. Chickens abides against an ineffective drill."
highlights = ["vet","funds"]
sentencesWithHighlights = []
```

**Most intuitive way:**

```
for sentence in sent_tokenize(paragraph):
    for highlight in highlights:
        if highlight in sentence:
            sentencesWithHighlights.append(sentence)
            break
```

But using this method we actually have what is effectively a 3x nested `for` loop. This is because we first check each `sentence`, then each `highlight`, then each subsequence in the `sentence` for the `highlight`.

**We can get better performance since we know the start index for each highlight:**

```
highlightIndices = [100,169]
subtractFromIndex = 0
for sentence in sent_tokenize(paragraph):
    for index in highlightIndices:
        if 0 < index - subtractFromIndex < len(sentence):
            sentencesWithHighlights.append(sentence)
            break
    subtractFromIndex += len(sentence)
```

**In either case we get:**

```
sentencesWithHighlights = ['Chickens crushes a popular vet next to the eater.', 'Coffee funds chickens.']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, simple and easy to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all your sentences end with one of these three characters: `!?.`

What about looping over the list of highlights, creating a regexp group:

```
(?:list|of|your highlights)
```

Then matching your whole abstract against this regexp:

```
/(?:[\.!\?]|^)\s*([^\.!\?]*(?:list|of|your highlights)[^\.!\?]*?)(?=\s*[\.!\?])/ig
```

This way you would get the sentence containing at least one of your highlights in the first subgroup of each match ([RegExr](http://regexr.com?3474v)).

Answer (score 0):

Another option (though it's tough to say how reliable it would be with variably defined text), would be to split the text into a list of sentences and test against them:

```
re.split('(?<=\?|!|\.)\s{0,2}(?=[A-Z]|$)', text)
```